# Django: change default label content in views.py or other methods

Tags: html, django

```
class SchoolUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = models.School
    fields = ('name', 'principal')
    labels = {'name': '學校名稱：', 'principal': '學校校長', 'location': '學校地址'}
```

It won't work, still showed name, principal, location; not the language I want.
And I have tried to use jQuery to modify it. But it is `<label for="id_age">Age:</label>` as default set in html without given id.

Comment: Use UTF-8 encoding to save your code to be safe.

Comment: Can I see you're form and model, I think you need to inherit from ModalForm and not default Form, and true `attrs` you can modify the `label` or use [verbose_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#verbose-name) in the model for translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views don't have attributes to define labels. Instead define a form class and set them there.

```
class SchoolForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('name', 'principal')
        labels = {'name': '學校名稱：', 'principal': '學校校長', 'location': '學校地址'}

class SchoolUpdateView(UpdateView):
    form_class = SchoolForm
```